# A question about powers of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

I have been running in circles trying to conceptualize the solution to this and am looking for a little guidance. I think the biggest problem is in trying to visualize how taking powers of a complex number cause that number to move in the complex plane. For example: visualizing the location of $z^n$ vs. the location of $z$ (for some integer $n$).

In general, I can see that it is not true that $|1+z^2|>|z^2|$ holds for some $z$ in the complex numbers as it does over the reals. For example, we could take $z=i$ as a counterexample. However, is there some bound we could put on $z$ (like $|z|>1$) that would make it true?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's not immediately obvious. Take a look at this for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set

Comment: Note that $|1+z^2|>|z^2|$ can be written as $|1+w|>|w|$ where $w=z^2.$ Given any $w$ there is some $z.$  This is true when $w=a+bi$ where $a>\frac12.$ The set of $z$ includes $c+di$ with $|c|\geq|d|,$ but there are more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I'm not sure it will help with your broader goal of visualizing powers of complex numbers, we can determine the exact set of points $z$ such that $|1+z^2|>|z^2|$.

First let's consider the related inequality $|1+w|>|w|$ for a complex number $w$. Squaring both sides and using the fact that $|a|^2 = a \overline a$, the inequality is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
|1+w|^2 &> |w|^2 \\
(1+w)(1+\overline w) &> w \overline w \\
1 + w + \overline w &> 0 \\
2\mathop{\rm Re(w)} &> -1.
\end{align*}
In other words, $|1+w|>|w|$ if and only if $w$ lies in the right half-plane $\mathop{\rm Re(w)} > -\frac12$.

Now we only have to determine the set of complex numbers $z$ such that $\mathop{\rm Re(z^2)} > -\frac12$. If we write $z=x+iy$, then $z^2 = x^2 + 2ixy - y^2$ and thus $\mathop{\rm Re(z^2)} = x^2-y^2$. The solutions of $x^2-y^2 > -\frac12$ comprise the region between the two branches of the hyperbola $y^2-x^2 = \frac12$. Therefore these are the complex numbers $z$ such that $|1+z^2|>|z^2|$ (the light-colored region in the graph below; notice $z=i$ lies outside this region, as you have observed).

[image]

Comment: Wow! Very thorough reply. Thank you, this helped a lot. Cheers.